# Apache virtual host documentroot in other folders

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to set up a couple ov VritualHost in my Apache, but I would like to put the DocumentRoot of these virtual host on folders outside the basic www folder.
It happens that I get alwasy "Permission Denied".
My httpd.conf follows:
NameVirtualHost *:80

```
         <VirtualHost *:80>
              ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
              DocumentRoot /home/giuseppe/www

              ServerName www.example.com/www
              ErrorLog logs/host.www.projects-error_log
              CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common

         <Directory "/home/giuseppe/www">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
         </Directory>

         </VirtualHost>


        <VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
             DocumentRoot /home/developper

             ServerName www.example.com
             ErrorLog logs/host.developper-error_log
             CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
        </VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:

I tried to change the user group permission to www folder. But no success.
I think the problem is ServerName.

```
 VirtualHost A
  ServerName www.example.com

 VirtualHost B
  Servername www.example.com/www
```

Maybe ServerName must be a valid DNS? Like www.example.com and site2.example.com, and not a simple

Comment: Where are your docs stored? How are you linking the docs? With a symlink? although you have `FollowSymLinks` you may need another `<Directory>` defintion to allow access to those files.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `DocumentRoot` where you want, no special restrictions on that.

So as stated by the error message your problem is only with file & directories rights.

The apache user must be able to walk to these documentRoots and to read files there. So you should adjust several things:

- check that either the apache user or group as read access on directories and files inside this directory
- check that he's got the execution right on all parents directories
- check that you do not have SELinux or such security tools adding some more constraints (check the apache logs and system logs)